# how to check session store used by node application

Tags: node.js, express, session, session-variables, express-session

Currently, I have a node application where I need to check the specific session store I am using to manage store session variables. I never explicitly configured this (though someone else working on the same codebase could have) and haven't been able to find anything specific, and I need to know if the session store uses the touch method to know if I should set the resave proprty of sessions to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to locate the express-session usage in your code base.

Should be in your server.js or app.js file. Being used as

```
app.use(session({...properties}));
```

For example it may look like this:

```
app.use(session({
        saveUninitialized: true,
        resave: true,
        secret: 'secret-123',
        cookie: { secure: false, httpOnly: true, maxAge: 60000 },
        store: new CouchbaseStore({
            db: connectionObj,
            prefix: 'test'
        })
    }));
```

the default store is the Memory of the server. So you can override the store with connect-mongo, connect-couchbase, connect-redis and what not.